# Is there any difference in meaning between "dry" and "dry off"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between *dry* and *dry off? For example:

> Let the fruit dry (**off**) before eating.

I cannot see any difference, but I am very curious to know what would make native English speakers go for *dry off* when *dry* is a bit shorter. What flavor of meaning does *off* add there?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the phrase **dry off** (as opposed to **dry it off**) is generally used (intransitively) when evaporation serves to dry a person/creature or object, as in:

> Give me a few minutes to dry off after my swim.
>   Make sure that the dog dries off before it comes inside.
>   Leave the umbrella outside to dry off.
>   Hang these clothes on the line; they will soon dry off in the sun.

although the **off** is optional in the last two examples.
It is also optional in the following examples in which the phrase is split:

> Dry yourself off with this towel.
>   Dry the car off with the cloth.

**Dry** - without **off**  (whether adjective or verb) can be used in any context. Often, it's just a matter of choice.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dry-off

Comment: Also, Dmytro's sentence presumably does not refer to _drying_ fruit in the sense of evaporating away its internal moisture, just to getting rid of any surface dampness.

Comment: I am sorry, but... So let's say I want the moisture to be removed from the surface of the fruit by laing in the sun. Do I say "let the fruit dry" or "let the fruit dry off"?

Comment: **Let the fruit dry off** makes it clear although **let the fruit dry** is grammatically correct. You could be clearer still by adding **outside** or **in the sun**.